# O parâmetro use_include_path foi substituído pelo parâmetro flags?

Tags: php, documentação

Eu costumo usar sempre a documentação em inglês do PHP, pois me parece que ela está sempre mais atualizada, porém ao acessar a documentação do `file_get_contents` em português, notei as seguintes mensagens:

```
string file_get_contents ( string $filename [, int $flags [, resource $context [, int $offset [, int $maxlen ]]]] )
```

`flags`:

> Aviso
>
> Para todas as versões anteriores ao PHP 6, este parâmetro é chamado use_include_path e é um bool. O parâmetro flags está disponível somente a partir do PHP 6. Se você estiver usando uma versão anterior e quiser buscar o arquivo filename no include_path, este parâmetro deve ser TRUE. A partir do PHP 6, você deve usar a flag FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH.

Changelog

- 5.0.0 Adicionado suporte a contexto.
- 5.1.0 Adicionados os parâmetros `offset` e `maxlen`.
- 6.0.0 O parâmetro `use_include_path` foi substituído pelo parâmetro `flags`.

Porém na documentação em inglês está assim:

> Note:
>
> As of PHP 5 the FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH constant can be used to trigger include path search.

Ou seja, me parece que a informação em Português diz que a parâmetro `$flags` é desde a versão 6 e no documentação em Inglês o parâmetro `$flags` é usado desde a versão 5.

Isto é algum erro na documentação em Português? Eu usei `FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH` e funcionou perfeitamente com PHP5, isto me faz pensar que a documentação em Portugues não é confiavel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não estou certo disto, mas acredito ser algo errôneo mesmo na documentação

Antes do anuncio do *PHP7* (Ué vai lançar o PHP7 sem o PHP6? - Vou explicar isto ao longo das resposta.) previsto para Setembro de 2015, houve muitas especulações sobre o PHP6, até mesmo um numero considerável de livros lançados que abordavam o PHP6 mesmo ele não existindo ainda, estes livros explicavam sobre muitas coisas que foram implementadas do PHP5.4+ ou situações que realmente não existem.

A documentação do PHP é "colaborativa" e cada idioma é uma página "fork" da versão em inglês, eu acredito que devido as estes livros/informações (que abordavam o suposto PHP6) tenham "enganado" os colaboradores das documentação.

### PHP6 existe (existiu)?

Não o PHP6 não existiu, houve muitas confusões sobre o assunto, pois sempre que alguma informação era levada a publico sobre novidades que seriam lançadas no PHP6 muitos se aproveitavam de tal informação (ou se enganavam) e saiam replicando tal informação sem a certeza do futuro.

Podemos dizer que parte do que seria PHP6 está no PHP5.4+ (ou no PHP5.6) e a outra parte não foi "definida ainda".

### O parâmetro use_include_path foi substituído pelo parâmetro flags?

Conforme o exemplo da [documentação em inglês](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php#example-2554):

```
<?php
// Example #2 Searching within the include_path
// <= PHP 5
$file = file_get_contents('./people.txt', true);
// > PHP 5
$file = file_get_contents('./people.txt', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
?>
```

A mudança ocorre do PHP4 para o PHP5 e este links confirmam:

- [Docs for page FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH.php](https://pear.php.net/reference/PHP_Compat-1.0.0RC1/PHP_Compat/_PHP_Compat-1.0.0RC1_Compat_Constant_FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH_php.html)
- [Predefined Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.constants.php)

> `FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH` (integer) Search for filename in `include_path` (since PHP 5).

### Resolvendo problemas da documentação

Note que é possível relatar bugs **na documentação** ou editar:

- https://edit.php.net/?project=PHP&perm=pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php
- https://bugs.php.net/report.php?bug_type=Documentation+problem&manpage=function.file-get-contents

Podemos supor com isto que foi uma edição mal realizada devido a uma informação errada e que é possível editar e corrigir isto.