# Habilitar PHP File Info Extension - runtime

Tags: php

Estou usando uma biblioteca chamada Intervention/Image no Laravel 4.2.
Em determinada página uso essa biblioteca para cortar imagens, mas não está fazendo isso porquê se exige que habilite ou instale essa extensão.

No localhost funciona, no servidor não.

[image: Foto do Erro]

Mas eu não tenho acesso ao PHP.INI do servidor.

Tem como habilitar essa DLL em tempo real ?

Comment: onde fica seu servidor? você pode criar um php.ini no raiz para importar somente essa dll geralmente os provedores de hospedagem permitem esse tipo de ação.

Comment: É só eu criar um arquivo **php.ini** e adicionar essa linha: `extension=php_fileinfo.dll` ?

Comment: Você tem que colocar o caminho absoluto... provavelmente vai ser /home/seuusuario/public_html/arquivo.dll e o php.ini fica na pasta public_html, mas isso seria no linux e o tipo de extensão seria ".so" e não ".dll". se você pudesse me informar qual o tipo de hospedagem que vc tem seria bom. Exemplo pode ser pelo painel, é Plesk ou Cpanel ?

Comment: cPanel. É pra ser Linux. Eu não tenho acesso.

Comment: Resolvido. Eu corri atrás do servidor. Não teve jeito. Habilitei a DLL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em tempo de execução para habilitar uma extensão você deve usar `dl`:

```
dl('/path/fileinfo.so');
```

Mas eu tenho quase certeza que isto não irá funcionar devido a nível de permissão dos usuários.

> Conforme [@bfavaretto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/habilitar-php-file-info-extension-runtime/70985?noredirect=1#comment145869_70985) - **Atenção**: A função `dl` foi removida em alguns SAPIs no PHP 5.3.

Você pode tentar usar o `.htaccess` e adicionar isto ao arquivo (nunca utilizei isto):

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_extension fileinfo.so
</IfModule>
```

Comment: [***Warning**
This function has been removed from some SAPIs in PHP 5.3*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php) (a versão em português do manual omite isso).

Comment: @bfavaretto É verdade a documentação em português está bem desatualizada http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/67950/3635