# Como utilizar prepared statements com variáveis externas em MySQLi

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, segurança

Tenho o seguinte código, no qual quero utilizar `prepared statments`:

`prepare.php`:

```
<?php
include "../conex.php"; // conecta

mysqli_set_charset($mysqli,"utf8"); // Transforma em UTF8 pra gravar acentos no servidor

// Inserção de variáveis do formulário no banco de dados

$sql = "INSERT INTO tabela (userid, username, meses, percdev)
VALUES ('$user_id', '$user_name', '$meses', '$percdev')";

if ($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $mysqli->error;
}

$mysqli->close();
```

Esse código funciona corretamente, gravando as variáveis no banco. Como coloquei esse código sozinho num arquivo, todas essas variáveis estão em arquivos externos. A estrutura é mais ou menos assim:

`index.php` -> formulário onde pega os valores das variáveis

`script.php` -> onde as variáveis são declaradas, e feitas algumas operações matemáticas. p.ex:

```
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese');
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

include "datas/tempo.php";

$percDevIns = empty($_POST['Tpercentdev']) ? NULL : $_POST['Tpercentdev'];

$valorIns = (788.00 * $percDevIns) / 100;
```

`saida.php` -> O arquivo chamado pelo `index.php` na `action` do `form`, no qual é chamado o `script.php` (no `head`):

```
include "../../models/scripts/script.php";
// todo o HTML e PHP da página de saída
```

E no final deste arquivo está a chamada para o arquivo `prepare.php`, que inclui as variáveis no banco (já com as modificações de `script.php`).

Então seguindo alguns tutoriais, e algumas perguntas daqui mesmo, tentei assim:

```
<?php
include "../conex.php";

// Transforma em UTF8 pra gravar acentos no servidor

mysqli_set_charset($mysqli,"utf8");

// Inserção de variáveis do formulário no banco de dados

$sql = "INSERT INTO tabela (userid, username, meses, percdev)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

$stmt->bind_param('isii', $user_id, $user_name, $meses, $percdev);

$stmt->execute();
printf("Error: %s.\n", $stmt->error);
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

Mas não grava no banco, e não me retorna nenhum erro... O que estou fazendo errado?

Comment: O autocommit está ligado?

Comment: Impressão minha, ou não foi declarado o `prepare` ?

Comment: Ah @Edilson... my bad... já coloquei o `prepare`, mas ainda to obtendo uns erros, mas acho que isso era o principal... Vou só conferir aqui e já retorno. Valeu.

Comment: @Edilson era isso mesmo... eu tava usando `$sql` ao invés de `$stmt = $mysqli->prepare`...  valeu, posta uma reposta aí.

Comment: Vou `Editar` a resposta abaixo, para evitar que a página se estenda demasiado, e fico feliz por ter ajudado.

Comment: Ok @Edilson, valeu mesmo! Abraços.

Comment: Prontos, achei melhor editar, e aproveitar a onda, porque às vezes o `commit` faz com que as informações não sejam gravadas de forma permanente no banco de dados/tabela. É só escolher a resposta para que se encerre a pergunta.

Comment: @Edilson não entendi, o commit "as vezes". Na verdade o commit é usado quando o autocommit está desligado para que seja possivel usar rollbacks, ou seja se você executar várias querys e uma falhar, você poderá fazer o rollback em todas anteriores e impedir que atualizações e inserções parciais entrem no banco. O commit só funciona quando o autocommit está desligado, pois se usar com ele ligado então é apenas redundância :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro, recomendo que se for usar orientado a objetos então use todos eventos do mysqli como oop e mais um detalhe parece que você esqueceu o `mysqli_stmt_prepare`, faça assim:

```
<?php
include "../conex.php";

// Transforma em UTF8 pra gravar acentos no servidor

$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")

// Inserção de variáveis do formulário no banco de dados

$sql = "INSERT INTO tabela (userid, username, meses, percdev)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql))
{
    $stmt->bind_param('isii', $user_id, $user_name, $meses, $percdev);

    $stmt->execute();
    printf("Error: %s.\n", $stmt->error);
    $stmt->close();
    $mysqli->close();
}
```

Se for usar procedural, então não use `$stmt->bind_param` use `mysqli_stmt_bind_param`, assim:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO tabela (userid, username, meses, percdev)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)';

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $sql))
{
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'isii', $user_id, $user_name, $meses, $percdev);

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

Se o script está executando normalmente, mas os resultados não estão gravando, pode ser o *autocommit* que esteja desligado.

Com isto você pode tentar "ligar" `autocommit`:

```
<?php
include "../conex.php";

// Transforma em UTF8 pra gravar acentos no servidor
mysqli_set_charset($mysqli,"utf8");

$mysqli->autocommit(true);//Liga o autocommit
```

Você também pode testar se o `INSERT`, `UPDATE` ou `REPLACE` afetaram a tabela usando `mysqli_affected_rows`:

```
$stmt->execute();
printf("Error: %s.\n", $stmt->error);
printf("%d linhas inseridas.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);
$stmt->close();
```

Se retornar `0` é porque **não** é um problema com o `autocommit`, pois mesmo **desligado** ele *emite* o valor de linhas afetadas maior que `0` se a query for bem sucedida.

Se você quer (precisa) usar `rollbacks`, então desligue o `autocommit` e no final use `mysql_commit` após o processe estiver ok:

```
$stmt->execute();
printf("Error: %s.\n", $stmt->error);
$stmt->close();

$mysqli->commit();
$mysqli->close();
```

**Documentação:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.autocommit.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Comment: Valeu cara, to vendo aqui...   +1

Comment: Então, incluindo `printf("%d linhas inseridas.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);` = Error: . 0 linhas inseridas. Você falou sobre OO, mas não, to usando procedural mesmo, é que criei uma divisão de pastas tipo MVC, mas to só começando a aprender OO, e não vou/posso mudar o projeto inteiro... Valeu por enquanto...

Comment: E em procedural ficaria como? Eu to vendo por [aqui](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) e na parte de mysqli diz que é `bind_param` e em PDO é `bindParam`... como disse ainda to aprendendo, e achei que pra OO era PDO e procedural era mysqli...

Comment: Editei a tua resposta, espero que não te importes @GuilhermeNascimento.

Comment: @Edilson eu não tinha visto teu comentário com a solução, obrigado, no entanto eu já havia editado, com exemplo oop e procedural (o caso do AP ele usa procedural), mas mesmo assim fico muito grato

Comment: Não há problema, o importante é que a dúvida esta esclarecida. Outra coisa é, que no `prepare` o `$stmt->prepare($sql);` deveria ser `$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)`, porque ele encerrou a `conexão` com `$mysqli->close()`. É só editar essa parte.

Comment: @Edilson Kk foi na hora de copiar da doc - ok obrigado

Comment: Perfeito! Valeu a ambos!

Comment: @gustavox evite a documentação do w3schools e do php.net em portugues, veja: http://www.w3fools.com e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/66277/3635