# PHP- Mysql Retornando erro: Call to undefined function

Tags: php, sql

Boa noite, estou tentando fazer uma conexão com o banco de dados.
E o  mysql está retornando o seguinte erro.:

> Call to undefined function mysql_connect_db()

Segue meu código:

```
<?PHP

//

$servidor ='localhost';
$usuario ='root';
$senha ='';
$banco= 'agenda';

// executando a conexão com o servidor

$link = mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$senha);

// selecionando o banco de dados

$select = mysql_connect_db($banco);

// Aqui insere os novos usuários

$nome= $_POST["nome"];
$telefone= $_POST["telefone"];
$email= $_POST["email"];

$sql= mysql_query("INSERT INTO CONTATO(NOME,TELEFONE,EMAIL) VALUES ('$nome','$telefone','$email')");

// executando todas as chamadas do sql e armazenando os dados.

$result =  mysql_query($sql);

echo "CADASTRO REALIZADO COM SUCESSO !";


?>
```

Comment: Colega, facilite nossa ajuda. teu script é pequeno, coloque aqui o mesmo. Além de tentarmos ajudar temos que ficar entrando em link externo? Complica né...

Answer (score 5):

O primeiro problema (que é o que causou o erro) é você ter inventado uma função.

A função `mysql_connect_db` não existe. Provavelmente você confundiu com `mysql_select_db`.

Problemas básicos como esse são resolvidos lendo ao menos o básico da documentação.

O problema que tem logo depois, conforme [explicado pelo colega Simão Ítalo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/132045/70), é a mistura de duas bibliotecas diferentes. Como ele demonstrou na resposta dada, o `mysqli` não precisa de uma função separada para selecionar o DB *default*. Isto é feito na conexão:

```
$link = mysqli_connect( $servidor, $usuario, $senha, $banco );
                                                     ^^^^^^
```

Lembrando sempre que você pode usar a sintaxe a seguir, caso prefira omitir o banco ao conectar, e/ou precise selecionar dados de bancos diferentes (afinal, o DB *default* é usado apenas em caso de omissão na *query*):

```
SELECT id, nome FROM banco1.cadastro ORDER BY nome
                     ^^^^^^
```

Em seguida, você está *cometendo um dos crimes mais bárbaros da segurança*<sup><sub>TM</sub></sup>, que é usar os dados sem nenhum tipo de sanitização:

```
$nome = $_POST["nome"];
$telefone = $_POST["telefone"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
```

Como consequência, cedo ou tarde você vai ter seu DB apagado ou corrompido, e tendo seu sistema e toda espéce de dados do DB usadas indevidamente.

A solução mais simples é sanitizar os dados, e tanto no caso do `mysql` quanto do `mysqli`, há funções apropriadas para isto. No caso do `mysqli`:

```
$nome = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $link, $_POST["nome"] );
$telefone = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $link, $_POST["telefone"] );
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $link, $_POST["email"] );
```

Isto pode te ajudar a entender melhor:

> [Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/70)

Na verdade, por questão de performance (e de fazer a coisa certinho) teria que caprichar mais e ver se realmente existem os dados postados, mas em termos de segurança, o que importa é a sanitização acima (e acertar o conjunto correto de caracteres usado pelo script).

Melhor que isso seria usar *prepared statements*, que apesar de não serem nem mais nem menos seguros que a correção acima, tem uma performance muito superior no caso de *queries* com várias linhas, além de organizar melhor o código.

> [Como utilizar prepared statements com variáveis externas em MySQLi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88644/70)

Além disto, bom lembrar que usando `mysqli` no modo procedural, o `$link`costuma ser sempre o primeiro parâmetro:

```
$sql = mysqli_query( $link, 'INSERT ...
```

O que leva a mais um equívoco no seu código, pq você logo em seguida tenta fazer a "*query* da *query*":

```
$result = mysql_query( $link, $sql );
```

Esta série de coisas dá uma impressão de "programação orientada a chute". Não entenda isto como uma ofensa, mas sim como uma crítica construtiva para melhorar sua atenção com o básico, senão corre o risco de viver de *copy & paste* como um monte de gente que pensa que é programador mas não é, e o que queremos é que você realmente aprenda e evolua.

Assim, segue o código ajustado:

```
<?php
    $servidor ='localhost';
    $usuario ='root';
    $senha ='';
    $banco= 'agenda';

    // estabelecendo a conexão com o servidor

    $link = mysqli_connect( $servidor, $usuario, $senha, $banco );

    // Aqui insere os novos usuários

    $nome = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $link, $_POST['nome'] );
    $telefone = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $link, $_POST['telefone'] );
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $link, $_POST['email'] );

    // quebrei em duas linhas só pra facilitar a leitura

    $sql = "INSERT INTO CONTATO( nome, telefone, email)";
    $sql .= " VALUES ( '$nome', '$telefone', '$email' )";

    // executando todas as chamadas do sql e armazenando os dados.

    $result = mysqli_query( $link, $sql );

    if( $result ) {
       echo 'CADASTRO REALIZADO COM SUCESSO!';
    } else {
       echo 'CADASTRO NAO REALIZADO!';
    }
?>
```

Obviamente que só dá pra testar em condições reais, então, se tiver qualquer problema a mais que tenha passado despercebido, basta deixar um comentário que a gente revisa.

Answer (score 1):

Se você está utilizando `mysqli_` para se conectar ao banco de dados, esqueça qualquer método que inicie com o prefixo `mysql_`, pois são métodos diferentes para tratar com BD.

Tente fazer da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
    /* configuração da conexão */
    $conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "senha", "nome_do_bd");

    /* checar se a conexão foi estabelecida com sucesso */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        exit();
    }

    /* inserindo dados em tabela */
    mysqli_query( $conexao, "INSERT INTO CONTATO(nome, telefone, email) VALUES ('Santiago','558899338844','email@teste.com')");
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Olá uma forma de fazer uma conexão bem sucedida poderia ser feita utilizando o PDO.
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/intro.pdo.php

```
<?php
    class PDOUtil 
    {
        private static $conexao = null;
        public static function getStance() 
        {
            try 
            {
                if (self::$conexao == null) 
                {
                    self::$conexao = new PDO ('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=BASE_DE_DADOS','USUARIO','SENHA');
                }
            } catch (PDOException $excecao) 
            {
                if ($excecao->getCode () == "2002") 
                {
                    echo 'Oi infelizmente seu Host nao foi encontrado, verifique isso com o web-master.';
                }
                if ($excecao->getCode () == "1049") 
                {
                    echo 'Oi infelizmente seu banco nao foi encontrado, verifique isso com o web-master.';
                }
                if ($excecao->getCode () == "1044") 
                {
                    echo 'Oi infelizmente seu usuario nao foi encontrado, verifique isso com o web-master.';
                }
                if ($excecao->getCode () == "1045") 
                {
                    echo 'Oi infelizmente sua senha nao foi encontrada, verifique isso com o web-master.';
                }
            }
            return self::$conexao;
        }
    }
```

Comment: O que foi depreciado foi mysql -> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration55.deprecated.php

Comment: realmente me equivoquei, deixei apenas a conexão PDO @João