# Símbolo "->" no php

Tags: php

Quando usei o PHPmailer eu usei (sem saber porque) o símbolo "->" em `$mail->AddAdress(...`, por exemplo. Agora tirando uma dúvida no W3schools (`http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp`) vi essa setinha "->" de novo em`$conn->connect_error`.

O que exatamente significa esse "->" símbolo?

(tentei colocar no google mas ele nem mesmo lê o símbolo como uma string, parece que ele incorpora como um caracter especial como +)

Comment: O símbolo `->` é restrito a objetos, para referenciar objetos de uma determinada instância. Como o usuário acima acabou de dizer, isso já possui respostas numa pergunta anteriormente feita.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O simbolo é usado pra chamar um método ou variável de uma classe. Antes de tudo você precisa entender o que é uma classe, se você já ouviu falar de *OOP* ou de *Orientado a objetos* então você entenderá o uso do `->`

Em várias linguagens de programação temos classes e a maioria se comporta de forma semelhante, no caso do PHP você pode criar uma classe sua assim:

```
class Enrique
{
    public function nome()
    {
        return 'Enrique';
    }
}
```

E chamar assim:

```
$test = new Enrique;
echo $test->nome(); //Irá exibir "Enrique" (sem aspas)
```

Veja que pra chamar o método `nome` da classe Enrique foi necessário usar `->`, desta maneira você chama as funções internas da classe.

Você também pode chamar o método dentro de outro método usando o `$this`

```
class Enrique
{
    public function nome()
    {
        return 'Enrique ' . $this->sobrenome(); //Junta o sobrenome ao nome e joga no return
    }

    public function sobrenome()
    {
        return 'René';
    }
}
```

Usando:

```
$test = new Enrique;
echo $test->nome(); //Irá exibir "Enrique René" (sem aspas)
```

A partir do PHP 5 estão a inclusão de [visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php), classes e métodos [abstract](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php) e [final](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php), [metodos mágicos](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php), [interfaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php), [clonagem](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) e [indução de tipo](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php).

O PHP trata objetos da mesma maneira que referencias ou manipuladores, significando que cada variável contém uma referencia a um objeto ao invés de uma cópia de todo o objeto. Veja [Objetos e Referencias](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php)

> Coloquei o manual em inglês, porque o em Português pode conter algumas falhas (como mencionei aqui: [O parâmetro use_include_path foi substituído pelo parâmetro flags?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/66277/3635))

O `->` tem o trabalho de acessar métodos ou propriedades de uma classe, assim como no Java e no C# o equivalente seria o `.`. O *"provável"* motivo do PHP não usar p `.` é porque ele já é usado pra outra tarefa no PHP, cada linguagem tem a sua tipagem, mas é bem provável que encontrar sempre algo equivalente.

### Classe em Java

```
class Enrique {
    public String nome()
    {
        return 'Enrique';
    }
}

class Programa {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Enrique test = new Enrique();

    System.out.println("Saldo atual: " + test.nome());
  }
}
```

### Conclusão

Então o básico do que é uma classe, lhe digo que o `PHPmailer` é uma classe (ou melhor um conjunto de classes e outras funções) e o link que você colocou é um exemplo do `mysqli` que é uma classe nativa do PHP pra conexão com o mysql, você pode usar tanto estrutural quanto *orientado a objeto* (classes), veja que aqui começou com `new`, quando ver ele em algum código provavelmente será uma classe:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

### Visibilidade em classes

Isto é uma característica que existe em várias linguagens que usam classes (existe exceções como o Python), a visibilidade é uma `keyword` que vai a frente do método ou variável na classe e define quem pode acessa-lo:

- `public` é quando está disponível pra ser acessado por "qualquer um", por exemplo `sobrenome` é acessível fora da classe e dentro, como no exemplo:

  ```
  class Enrique
  {
      public function nome()
      {
          return 'Enrique ' . $this->sobrenome(); //Junta o sobrenome ao nome e joga no return
      }

      public function sobrenome()
      {
          return 'René';
      }
  }

  $test = new Enrique;
  $test->sobrenome();
  ```
- `private` é quando o método ou variável são acessíveis apenas dentro da classe, se tentar acessar fora vai ocasionar uma `Exception`, por exemplo:

  ```
  class Enrique
  {
      public function nome()
      {
          return 'Enrique ' . $this->sobrenome(); //Aqui você pode acessar sobrenome normalmente
      }

      private function sobrenome()
      {
          return 'René';
      }
  }

  $test = new Enrique;
  $test->sobrenome(); //Aqui causa uma Exception
  ```

  Vai emitir este erro:

  > PHP Fatal error: Call to private method Enrique::sobrenome() from context '' in /home/zy4mrI/prog.php on line 16
- `protected` é semelhante ao private e causa o mesmo erro se acessado fora da classe, exceto que o método ou variável é acessível em todas as classes que estendem classe atual, incluindo a classe pai.

Leia mais em [Classes and Objects Visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

Comment: Não tinha visto sua resposta.. No mobile não aparece.

Comment: @emanuelsn sem problema, você informou algo que na minha não, o nome do operador :) +1

Answer (score 5):

O nome oficial é [Object operator](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php), mas, vejo por ai o pessoal chamando-o de 'setinha', 'seta' e 'flecha'.

Este é um operador usado para acessar os métodos de um objeto.

Por exemplo, quando você usa `$conn->connect_error`, você está acessando o método connect_error do objeto $conn.

Comment: +1 simples e objetivo

Answer (score 3):

(`T_OBJECT_OPERATOR`) `->` é um token utilizado para acessar métodos "não estáticos" de uma classe:

> `$this->prop` (onde `prop` é o nome da propriedade).

Esta "seta" e também outros símbolos, são herdados do **C/C++** e são utilizados pela maioria das linguagens de programação, incluindo o **PHP** e o seu mais novo irmão **Hack/HHVM**

Para quem programa em PHP, é muito importante conhecer todos os `parser tokens`:
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/tokens.php