# Mysqli INSERT INTO Não funciona

Tags: php, mysql

tenho um codigo que insere registros no banco de dados, ele não está exibindo nenhum erro, ele simplesmente não está enviando os dados para o banco de dados

o codigo funcionava anteriormente só que como o mysql_* se tornou obsoleta tive que atualizar, e ai ele parou de funcionar

aqui está o codigo

```
<?php
include "../../lib/inc_con.php";
session_start();
$mesa = $_POST['mesa'];
$tamanho = $_POST['tamanho'];
$quantidade = $_POST['qtd'];
$adicional = implode(',', $_POST['adicional']);
$hiddentotal = $_POST['hiddentotal'];
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo'); 
$mysqldata = new DateTime(); 
$data = $mysqldata->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
$produto_id1 = utf8_encode($_POST['produto_id1']);
$atendente_id = $_SESSION['id'];
$observacao = $_POST['observacao'];
$produzido = '0';
$valortotal = $quantidade * $hiddentotal;
$asplo = $_POST['asplo'];


$inserir = $conexao->query("INSERT INTO pedidos (mesa, tamanho, qtd, adicional, valortotal, data, produto_id1, atendente_id, produzido, observacao, asplo) 
values ('$mesa', '$tamanho', '$quantidade', '$adicional', '$valortotal', '$data', '$produto_id1', '$atendente_id', '$produzido', '$observacao', '$asplo'") or die (mysqli_error()); 
if($inserir){
    echo "Inserido";
} else {
    echo $inserir->error;
}

?>
```

arquivo inc_cong.php

```php
<?php

error_reporting(0);
ini_set(“display_errors”, 0 );

$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbdatabase = "moclient";

$conexao = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbdatabase);
if($conexao->connect_error){
    echo "Conexao:";?><span class="ls-tag-danger">Erro!</span>
<?php
}else{ 
    echo "Conexao:";?><span class="ls-tag-success">OK!</span>
<?php }

?>
```

Comment: Se você dar um echo na var $inserir ou copiar a query e dar um echo na query e testar direto realiza o insert?

Comment: Poste o conteúdo de `inc_con.php`.

Comment: <?php

error_reporting(0);
ini_set(“display_errors”, 0 );

$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbdatabase = "moclient";

$conexao = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbdatabase);
if($conexao->connect_error){
 echo "Conexao:";?><span class="ls-tag-danger">Erro!</span>
<?php
}else{ 
 echo "Conexao:";?><span class="ls-tag-success">OK!</span>
<?php }

?>

Comment: Embora não esteja a retornar erros, retorna sequer alguma mensagem ?

Comment: Retorna Conexão: OK!

Comment: Falo desta condição aqui `if($inserir)`, retorna _inserido_ ? Ou retorna o erro ?

Comment: Não retorna nada

Comment: Alfredo, seria bacana se tivéssemos bola cristal para advinhar o que se passa.. mas não temos..  Por isso existe o tal “feedback”..  vc apenas retorna coisas vagas...  se quer ajuda, ajude-nos a te ajudar.  mas atente-se de que isso aqui não é centro de suporte e ajuda. O seu trabalho é responsabilidade sua.

Comment: @AlfredoLima fez as alterações conforme eu sugeri na minha resposta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/95832/3635 ?

Answer (score 2):

Quando estiver em desenvolvimento use assim:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT); //Irá mostrar qualquer erro

$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbdatabase = "moclient";

$conexao = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbdatabase);
if($conexao->connect_error){
    echo "Conexao:";?><span class="ls-tag-danger">Erro!</span>
<?php
}else{ 
    echo "Conexao:";?><span class="ls-tag-success">OK!</span>
<?php }

?>
```

No caso você disse que retorna:

> Retorna Conexão: OK!

Mas isto é apenas da conexão, você deve ver o erro deste ponto, você esta usando duas verificações erro:

```
$inserir = $conexao->query("INSERT INTO pedidos (mesa, tamanho, qtd, adicional, valortotal, data, produto_id1, atendente_id, produzido, observacao, asplo) 
values ('$mesa', '$tamanho', '$quantidade', '$adicional', '$valortotal', '$data', '$produto_id1', '$atendente_id', '$produzido', '$observacao', '$asplo'") or die (mysqli_error()); //Erro aqui, abaixo não é executado
if($inserir){
    echo "Inserido";
} else {
    echo '', $inserir->error;//Este erro
}
```

Você usou o `or` sem necessidade, e outro detalhe você esta usando o formato orientado a objetos, então talvez `mysqli_error` esteja vindo vazio.

Use assim:

```
$inserir = $conexao->query("INSERT INTO pedidos (mesa, tamanho, qtd, adicional, valortotal, data, produto_id1, atendente_id, produzido, observacao, asplo) 
values ('$mesa', '$tamanho', '$quantidade', '$adicional', '$valortotal', '$data', '$produto_id1', '$atendente_id', '$produzido', '$observacao', '$asplo'");

if($inserir){
    $inserir->close(); //Fecha a execução da query query
    echo "Inserido";
} else {
    echo 'Erro: ', $inserir->error;//Exibe o erro
}
```

Recomendo que use exatamente como a documentação descreve:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

<sub>(Recomendo a documentação em Inglês porque algumas páginas em Português tem informações erradas - https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/67950/3635)</sub>

Quando enviar o script pra produção (pro site) então pode usar assim:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT); //Irá mostrar qualquer erro
```

### Adicionais

O `session_start();` deve vir antes de qualquer `echo`, `print` ou texto, então faça assim:

```
<?php
session_start();
include "../../lib/inc_con.php";
```

Answer (score -1):

O commit está setado para true?

Se não estiver, possivelmente esta é a solução para o seu problema. E neste caso, use `$mysqli->query('SET AUTOCOMMIT = 1');`

Comment: O que é AUTOCOMMIT?

Comment: Sem autocommit você mesmo deve commitar a execução do script para que ele seja persistido na base de dados.  Após executar o insert deveria colocar : $mysqli->commit(); caso  o não esteja configurado para realizar autocommit.

Comment: Na verdade seria _$mysqli->autocommit(true/false)_ para o teu caso, o método/declaração _commit_ torna permanentes quaisquer alterações feitas no banco de dados durante uma transação, que é onde são normalmente têm mais utilidade. E normalmente são usadas em consultas onde não queremos que os dados sejam alterados permanentemente logo que os inserimos, usando o _rollback_ podemos desfazer as mudanças, isso dependendo do estado do _commit_.