# PHP - Definindo tempo de SESSION em funções já definidas

Tags: php, session

Estou precisando definir o tempo de SESSION do meu site, que assumi de outro desenvolvedor.

As definições de Session são usadas a partir de um arquivo pronto, session.php

Segue o código desse arquivo:

```
<?php

// classe para gerenciar sessÃ£o
Class Session extends Singleton {    
protected function __construct() {
    if(!session_start()) {
        session_start();     
    }
}

public static function define($key,$val) {
    $classe = self::instance();
    $_SESSION[$key] = $val;
}

public static function apaga($key) {
    $classe = self::instance();
    unset($_SESSION[$key]);
}

public static function limpa() {
    $classe = self::instance();
    $_SESSION = array();

}

public static function retorna($key) {
    $classe = self::instance();
    if(!empty($_SESSION[$key])) {
        return $_SESSION[$key];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public static function define_dados($data = array()) {
    if(is_array($data)) {
        foreach($data as $key=>$val) {
            $_SESSION[$key] = $val;
        }
    }
}

public static function fecha() {
    session_write_close();
}
}

?>
```

Como eu poderia definir esse tempo pra 1 hora, por exemplo? Tentei várias coisas que procurei na internet, mas nada. Alguém tem alguma luz?

Answer (score 1):

A lógica das sessões é serem destruídas no momento que o "navegador fecha", todavia é possível controlar o tempo da "sessão" e do "cookie" que mantem a sessão.

Mas antes vou falar um problema no teu código, isto está errado:

```
protected function __construct() {
    if(!session_start()) {
        session_start();     
    }
}
```

Na verdade você está chamando apenas `!session_start`, o segundo nunca será executado, provavelmente você achou que o `!` faria apenas uma checagem, mas isto é um engano, ele é uma função, se ele falha o segundo tentará executar e irá falhar também. Ou seja não serve para nada mesmo.

Se quer verificar se uma sessão já esta iniciada você pode usar `session_status` (PHP5.4+) ou `session_id` para manter compatibilidade com o PHP5.3.

### Com session_id

Funciona em todas versões do **PHP5** (acredito que funcione no **PHP7** também, ao menos na documentação nada mudou):

```
protected function __construct() {
    if (session_id() === '') { //Se for vazio é porque não iniciou a sessão ainda
        session_start();     
    }
}
```

### Com session_status

Funcionará se for PHP5.4+:

```
protected function __construct() {
    if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
        session_start();     
    }
}
```

### Aumentar o tempo de vida de uma sessão

Agora para aumentar o tempo de sessão você deve usar [`session_set_cookie_params`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) e deve ser executado antes de `session_start`

> Nota: se for PHP7 você poderá configurar diretamente em `session_start`

```
protected function __construct() {
    if (session_id() === '') { //Se for vazio é porque não iniciou a sessão ainda
        $expiraem = 3600 * 24 * 1; // 1 dia
        session_set_cookie_params($expiraem);
        session_start();
    }
}
```

Se for PHP7:

```
protected function __construct() {
    //Se for vazio é porque não iniciou a sessão ainda
    if (session_id() === '') {
        session_start([
            'cookie_lifetime' => 3600 * 24 * 1 // 1 dia
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Recomendo que leia a documentação:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

> **NOTA:** documentação em português está muito desatualizada e costuma conter alguns problemas, por isto estou recomendando a em inglês.
>
> Um exemplo de problema na documentação em português: [O parâmetro use_include_path foi substituído pelo parâmetro flags?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/66277/3635)